# ESLint: Require statement not part of import statement.(@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires)

Tags: react-native, eslint

I'm trying to add a background image from react native **BackgroundImage** which needs to add source as `source={require('*--iamge path --*')}`

but my eslint throw **Require statement not part of import statement.** error. i have tried to import image in different ways for example:

```
 - const image = '--image path--'
 - import image = require('--image path--')
 - <BackgroundImage source={require('--image path--')}>
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890857/6666348

Answer (score 122, accepted):

you can disable this check in `eslintrc.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  rules: {
    ...
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0,
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the documentation for this? [eslint.org](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) is totally silent about this as far as I can tell.

Comment: You can check it here https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-var-requires.md

Comment: @samurai_jane There is no reason eslint.org should say anything about this. Eslint.org tells you the general form on how to enable and disable rules. Like here: `rulename: value`. These rules are from an external package, typescript-eslint, so why would eslint.org say anything about it? Everyone can create their own rules.

Answer (score 55):

It's also possible to disable it for individual files, instead of globally disabling it for the whole project.

Add at the top of the file:

```
/* eslint @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires: "off" */
```

Comment: Or `/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */`

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error with typescript lint, locally disable this rule by adding this line right before the require statement worked for me:

```
/* tslint:disable no-var-requires */
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create `.eslingignore` in your project same level as `.eslintrc.js` and add directories that you want to ignore.

That happened to me when I was working with react project with aws-amplify to communicate with aws. So I could either create another `.eslintrc.js` in amplify directory which has nodejs code. Instead, I created `.eslingignore` on the root level and added "amplify" directory.

Answer (score 0):

In ESLint config try to add this:

```
overrides: [
  {
    files: ['path-to-file', ...],
    rules: {
      '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    },
  },
],
```