# How to import Mapbox GL Draw in Angular 8 project

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl-draw

I'm working on a Angular 8 project with Webpack. I was able to integrate **Mapbox GL JS**, but I don't know how to import **Mabox GL Draw**. I have following versions:

```
"@angular/core": "8.2.14",
"mapbox-gl": "^1.9.0",
"@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.8.2",
"@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw": "^1.1.2",
```

I followed [Mapbox GL Draw docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw), so in my Angular Service, I added:

```
import * as MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';
```

So I've got this error:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw'. '/home/tommy/Work/engineering/effector/effector-gui/node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-draw` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';

Following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam) I try to use **require** instead of **import**:

```
const MapboxDraw = require('@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw');
```

I had this:

> 3:20  error  Require statement not part of import statement  @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonlint-lines/lib/jsonlint.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/user/proj/node_modules/jsonlint-lines/lib

So I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278151/eslint-require-statement-not-part-of-import-statement-typescript-eslint-no-va), I modified my **tsconfig.json** and I installed via npm "fs". But an error occurs:

> This dependency was not found:
>   * fs in ./node_modules/jsonlint-lines/lib/jsonlint.js
>   To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs
>   No type errors found

So I decided to get back to the first error and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927551/how-to-resolve-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-request-context). I modified **tsconfig.json** file adding these values:

```
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types","./types"],
...
  "exclude": ["node_modules","./types"]
```

Than I created **index.d.ts** file inside these three folders types/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/ with this content

```
declare module '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';
```

But I get this error

> ERROR in undefined(undefined,undefined):
>   TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@mapbox'.

Now I feel so close to solution, but I don't now how to go further.

Answer (score 0):

I created an additional *index.d.ts* file inside *types/@mapbox* folder with this content:

```
declare module '@mapbox';
```

But this time I got this back:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
This dependency was not found:
* fs in ./node_modules/jsonlint-lines/lib/jsonlint.js
To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs
```

And following [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/issues/626) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681) in my *webpack.common.js* file I added line related to *fs*:

```
module.exports = (options) => ({
    node: { fs: 'empty' },
    resolve: {
```

Then the code was compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get by with a `@ts-ignore` in my directive:

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as MapboxDraw from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw";
```

and this in the webpack config like @tommynicoletti's answer:

```js
module.exports = (options) => ({
    node: { fs: 'empty' },
    resolve: {
```