# Could not Import moment in Nestjs application

Tags: typescript, nestjs, momentjs

Could not use [**moment**](https://momentjs.com/) methods like `moment().utc().format()` shows below error message.

```js
TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof import("/nxdev/unified-ai/node_modules/moment/ts3.1- 
typings/moment.d.ts")' has no call signatures.
```

I tried to import moment as

```js
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

moment version: 2.29.4
node version: 18.14.0.

Comment: try to import it this way `const moment = require('moment');`

Comment: @hatana this is typescript code and its shows an error message.

Comment: yeah try my suggestion

Comment: shows error ESLint: Require statement not part of import statement.(@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires)

worked when import like import moment = require('moment');

Comment: This is an eslint error have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278151/eslint-require-statement-not-part-of-import-statement-typescript-eslint-no-va)

Answer (score 1):

according to this section in the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

> When exporting a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific import `module = require("module")` must be used to import the module.

so here since they are exporting with `export =` in the provided package you have to import this way

```js
const moment = require('moment');
```